Switch for switching between and/or gate
I am working on the following home project that is beyond my skillset. I need help:)
The project:
I am making a task tracker for every day of the week. For every day there are 2 switches (tasks), a red led and a green led. Overall there is one more switch that will act as a mode switch.
Mode switch to the left:
If one of the two switches is flipped up (for green) or flipped down (for red) the corrosponding led will light up.
Mode switch to the right:
Both switches needs to be in the same state in order to light up the corrosponding led.
For this I bought the following a couple (20) dpdt (double checked) switches because i thought that would be needed. I have leds and diodes but can buy whatever is needed ofcourse. It would be nice a dayswitch could set to green, neutral and red.
To keep it easy i would like to start with a single day, just the green led and a modeswitch. This way i can follow what is going on building up the whole 7 day system (7x2 switches + leds + 1 modeswitch). What would the diagram look like?
Side note: I am a programmer without a lot of eletrical skills so i thought it would be nice to keep it as mechanical as possible: just gates, diodes and what not. If possible i would like to stay away from controllers, tranistors etc but if that makes life easier i am all for it ofcourse.

Truth table:
     INPUT          OUTPUT
Sw0 | Sw1 | Sw2 | G.Led | R.Led
 0  |  0  |  0  |   0   |   0
 0  |  1  |  0  |   1   |   0
 0  |  2  |  0  |   0   |   1
 0  |  0  |  1  |   1   |   0
 0  |  0  |  2  |   0   |   1
 0  |  1  |  1  |   1   |   0
 0  |  2  |  2  |   0   |   1
 0  |  1  |  2  |   1   |   1
 0  |  2  |  2  |   1   |   1

 1  |  0  |  0  |   0   |   0
 1  |  1  |  0  |   0   |   0
 1  |  2  |  0  |   0   |   0
 1  |  0  |  1  |   0   |   0
 1  |  0  |  2  |   0   |   0
 1  |  1  |  1  |   1   |   0
 1  |  2  |  2  |   0   |   1
 1  |  1  |  2  |   0   |   0
 1  |  2  |  1  |   0   |   0


What does "other side of the switches" mean for the red LED control?

Only switches and steering diodes, or electronic components such as transistors and logic gates?  AND - Reference Designators - !

Welcome! Please add a truth table of your inputs (switches) and outputs (red and green LED).

I will update my question. It would be cool to to steer away from tranistors and logicgates but if there is not other way i can buy them ofcourse.  And the other way is as shown in Transistor answer: The end connected to nothing (nc?) is ment for the red led. So you can switch them between red and green led.

I note your table shows Sw1 and Sw2 have three possible states, 0, 1 & 2. What kind of switches have you got in mind? On-Off-On (centre-off) style? I've never seen a truth table for these. Maybe the three states would be better represented by -1, 0 and +1 or L, 0, R (keeping the 0 for centre-off).

Yes, i have on off on switches

Table 1. Logic truth table.
          mode
 S1 | S2 | S3 | G
----+----+----+----
 0  | 0  | 0  | 0
 1  | 0  | 0  | 1
 0  | 1  | 0  | 1
 1  | 1  | 0  | 1
----+----+----+----
 0  | 0  | 1  | 0
 1  | 0  | 1  | 0
 0  | 1  | 1  | 0
 1  | 1  | 1  | 1


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. A solution - but it requires two poles of SW3, the mode switch.

Thanks for the diagram! I am glad i even understand whats going on. So to be clear, you do not think it is possible to get this done with a spdt (still learning the differences). And if i may, how would it look like if the red led would be connected aswell. With my limited knowledge it looks to me i cannot reuse the same mode switch sw3a/b even tho i would really like that. And to make it even harder: I am planning on making 20 with a single modeswitch for it.I dont see how i can make that happening. Is the mode switch maybe to hard and i need to stick to a simpler design?

You really need to edit your question as requested. Explain what the real problem you are trying to solve is. What are the 20 (pairs of) LEDs for? Where are the switches? What is the equipment that it's going in?

Just did. I hope this helps. Thanks for helping me out so far!

I agree with Transistor's truth table.  Based on that, an all-mechanical solution takes one DPDT and two SPST switches per LED.
The S1 input always goes to the source, and the S2 output always goes to the LED.  Both the S1 output and the S2 input change connections based on S3, so S3 must have two poles.
